# change bootstrap progress bar background (not the bar, but the bars Background)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background, progress-bar

Currently I am using a bootstrap progress bar

```
<div class="progress">
 <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
60%
 </div>
</div>
```

the default color of the bar is blue, I have managed to change this.

However, the default background of the not filled in part is white with  grey radients, how can i change this to my own colour?

Answer (score 14):

You just need to overwrite the values on .progress with your own CSS.

```
.progress {
  background-color: #aaa;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

That will remove the shadow on the remainder of the progress bar, and change it to (in this case) a mild gray. You can pick whatever color value you'd like there.

That can go in the HTML itself (not generally preferred), or in your own CSS file (just make sure it's included after the Bootstrap CSS).

(A quick Plunkr to illustrate: http://plnkr.co/edit/WUDuq5XayN0nXEmtXY6V)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working, it changes the behind color. I changed it to black and you can just about see the backgrund layer behind both the bar and the uncolored bar change.

Comment: Are you manipulating the Bootstrap theme overall? It is true that the progress class will be behind the actual progress bar, but the default Bootstrap makes the bar the same size as the container so it visually wins out. If you've got some Bootstrap theme going on, that might change heights and allow .progress to peek through behind the bar.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by the theme overall? the css I use is:


<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "CSS/css/bootstrap.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "sheet.css"/>

Comment: I meant if you grabbed some "free Bootstrap theme" and applied it to your site. Doesn't look like you did, so you're okay. (Although, you don't need both the .min.css and the bootstrap.css files. Only one or the other.) Could you put up a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: picture added :) 

Ahh yeah I have both because i started edditing the bootstrap files I have, then it became outdated so got the online link. Hoever need to slowly delete the directory, and re do my bootstrap manipulation.

Answer (score 9):

You just need to put background color on progress to surround the bar:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="progress bg-warning">
 <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
60%
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a big help when using a text status inside the progress bar - and the default text was unreadable against the default background color when the bar was short.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this. either inline or in separate css file.

```
 <div class="progress" style="height:20px; border-radius: 0; background-color: #ffaab2;">
      <div class="progress-bar" style="width:80%;height:20px; background-color: #ff5262">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use contextual classes. adding a class like this would solve your issue:

```
class="progress-bar-success"
```

in order to use other colors you can change the "success" with:

- info: light blue
- danger: red
- warning: orange